# Clang: do I have to pass -O0 when compiling with coverage for PGO

Tags: clang, llvm, profiler, pgo

So I am compiling a big C++ program with clang 3.8.
I want to make use of PGO (Profile guided optimization). I want to use the way of compiling in instrumentation to generate the profile.

Currently I am passing `-fprofile-instr-generate --coverage` to the compiler and `--coverage` to the Linker.

So now the question is whether it would be optimal to pass `-O0` too, so the compiler can map back the calls from the binary during the next compilation properly. Or is that unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unnecessary. Coverage will be the same on optimized code, otherwise it would be worrisome ;)

For instance the clang coverage bot builds with `-O3  -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping`